# How to convert age+ to words

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

If I have "11+ years old children" in a sentence and I want to re-write the statement without the "+". What is the best alternative?

> For 11 years old or more children.

or

> For 11 or more years old children.

Comment: We don't use plurals in this kind of construction.  "The children are 11 **years** old" but "They are 11-**year**-old children."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic ways I can think of are

less formal: **Children 11 or older**

Example:

> ...[six were 11 or older.](https://books.google.com/books?id=sGhDAQAAMAAJ&q=%2211%20or%20older%22&dq=%2211%20or%20older%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwisk8adqez2AhWkVt8KHWsaAGw4ChDoAXoECAUQAg)

or

more formal: **Children (of) 11 or more [years of age](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/years-of-age)**

Examples:

> ...[care of ambulatory children of 12 or more years of age](https://books.google.com/books?id=oy9NAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA22-PP29&dq=%22of%2012%20or%20more%20years%20of%20age%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6xYSvqOz2AhUvhOAKHYrvBLkQ6AF6BAgLEAI)...

> [For any person 12 or more years of age](https://books.google.com/books?id=Nkd9ONpLbMgC&pg=PA407&dq=%22For%20any%20person%2012%20or%20more%20years%20of%20age%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7kqqKqez2AhXllIkEHff4B50Q6AF6BAgCEAI)...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably "11 or older", but a couple of alternatives.

You could say "older than 10".  This is mathematically the same, but tends to cause confusion. You can negate the condition:  "Not for children younger than 11".

You could use the fact that children start secondary school (in Britain) at age 11, so you could say "for secondary school students".  That may be relevant to the context. In the USA the equivalent would be "grade 6 and above" (although grades are not so tightly tied to ages as they are in the UK)

Toys and games are sometimes labeled as "for ages 11 to 99" (with the upper limit understood to be a joke)

If you want to be vague, then "adolescent" begins at about 11, although there is no universal definition. In a similar vein, books for 11-15 year-olds are sometimes labelled as "YA", short for "young adult".